# SQL - Trouble with simple select query

Tags: sql

I'm having some trouble figuring out why the SQL query below isn't working ... when `members_only` is set to 0, it's still showing them...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM reports 
 WHERE story = "1" 
    OR barebones = "1" 
   AND members_only = "1"
```

Comment: **Moderator note**: _Comments under this question were removed because they degenerated into flag attracting noise. Please keep comments constructive and related to the question at hand._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use brackets to distinguish your clarify the WHERE-condition.

```
SELECT * 
FROM reports 
WHERE (story = '1' OR barebones = '1')
  AND members_only = '1'
```

Answer (score 8):

It depends on your data, but you may not be aware that `AND` has higher precedence in SQL than `OR`, so your query really evaluates to this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM reports 
 WHERE story = '1'
    OR (barebones = '1' AND members_only = '1')
```

Consider using different brackets per the other answers to explicitly declare your intentions

Comment: But no unnecessary brackets - hate it when some brackets every single, individual WHERE clause.  Pointless...

Answer (score 3):

Missing parenthesis?
Did you want to do something like this:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM reports
 WHERE (story = "1" OR barebones = "1") AND members_only = "1"
```

Comment: @Admiral Nelson: You could change the OR into: `'1' IN (story, barebones)`

Comment: @OMG Ponies: That seems like a more complex operation. What would the query plan look like for that? Also, do you know if any SQL providers allow implicit conversion of 1 and 0 to TRUE and FALSE?

Comment: assuming they are all `int` types, `story + barebones + members_only > 1` :) if you want to make it even more confusing

Comment: @Admiral Nelson: You could test for yourself, because otherwise you can only take my word for things ;)  But `IN` is not syntactic sugar -- it typically does have a better query plan than `OR`.

Comment: To those who dismiss my suggested optimization as being "less readable", I await your inevitable "why is my query so slow..." questions on SO.  What good is "readable", if it doesn't scale/perform well?

Comment: @Admiral Nelson: SQL does not have a true Boolean (true/false) data type - BIT is ANSI I believe, which relies on values being numeric.

Answer (score 3):

I would say because it reads the query as:

```
WHERE (story = '1') OR (barebones = '1' AND members_only = '1')
```

since `story = '1'`, the condition is satisfied

OR clauses can be tricky - you often need to explicitly tell the query where it belongs. I assume, you want this:

```
WHERE (story = '1' OR barebones = '1') AND members_only = '1'
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing parenthesis.

**The following code will work, assuming members_only HAS to be "1", but only *story* or *barebones* has to be "1".**

```
SELECT * 
  FROM reports 
 WHERE 
    (story = "1" OR barebones = "1")
    AND members_only = "1"
```

You should read up on [TSQL Operator Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx)

In your original code, assume the following:

- *store* = 1
- *barebones* = 1
- *members_only* = 0

Due to Operator Precedence, *barebones* and *members_only* is evaluated first, and evaluates to false.

Following this, the result of the first boolean evaluation (`false`) (also known as `The Right Side`) is compared to (`story = "1"`) (also known as `The Left Side`).

`The Right Side` evaluates to false, but `The Left Side` evaluates to true.

Since the final boolean compression uses the `OR` operator, the end result is a `TRUE`, thus that record is indeed returned, no matter the value of either *barebones* or *members_only*, since `The Left Side` always evaluates to True.